# New to SQL - INCORRECT INTEGER. Laments terms, what does it mean?

Tags: sql, integer, error-code

**Error: Incorrect integer value: 'Hammer Mill' for column 'supplier_name' at row 1
Error Code: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD**

Context, I'm trying to build a database. I've been able to run the prior tables. I get to this one: **-- BRANCH SUPPLIER
INSERT INTO branch_supplier VALUES(2, 'Hammer Mill', 'Paper')**; and I get the errors mentioned above.

Comment: What database are you using? The error looks quite specific.

Comment: I'm learning to build one and I'm doing it on PopSQL. I'm following steps which led me up to this point and I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems self-explanatory to me, whatever the database you are using...
You are trying to insert a string value into an integer column and there are only two possible causes:

1. Either the table has been created with the wrong data types (or you are not respecting data types). I think this is your case as [supplier_name] as an int column sounds wrong to me
2. The "column order" is not the one you expect, if not specified it will be positional, meaning the first value goes into the first column... it's not wise for several reasons and I suggest you always use the below format for your insert

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value, ...);
```

Comment: So would column 1/2/3 be 2/Hammer Mill/Paper? If so, what would be the values? I thought the value would be 2. Or am I inserting the values from the table? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: ... columnX will be the name of the columns you want to populate and valueX will be the actual value... but as I stated your error is pretty clear and I think you have the wrong datatype for [supplier_name]